# R package not found, but present in correct library

Tags: r, package, gridextra

I have a problem with the R package "gridExtra". Everything is ok, when I go into R and load it, but when I execute a python script, which among others also loads this package, everything stops. I don't understand it, since I checked the library and the right library is selected.

It's a little complicated, because the script is from someone else. It can be accessed from here: https://github.com/guigolab/ggsashimi/blob/master/sashimi-plot.py. The package is loaded at row 430. Loading the previous packages was no problem, after installing them into the custom library. During the python script, a custom R script is generated and executed. Within this R script, the package is loaded usign the function `library(gridExtra)`.

The error message is:

`Error in library(gridExtra) : there is no package called â€˜gridExtraâ€™
Execution halted`

I checked, if the generated R script really accesses the right library and it does, so there is no problem with the library selection.

Comment: Please give a little bit more information.  How does the python script load `gridExtra`?  What is the error message?  What do you mean by "the right library is selected"?  Try to give a minimal example, i.e. a small python script that loads `gridExtra` and fails.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the question

Comment: It should be possible to distill a minimal example by removing lots of rows from sashimy-plot.py.

Comment: How did you install `gridExtra`?  Python calls R in line 527.  When you run `R --no-save` and then enter `library(gridExtra)`, it will probably fail.  The problem is that R looks for libraries at the wrong places.  Running `R --vanilla -e "install.packages('gridExtra')"` might install `gridExtra` at the correct location (if you have the rights to do so).  Otherwise you need to call R from python in such a way that it finds your libraries.

Comment: The condusing thing is, that I had the same error with the "ggplot2" package and after installing it, I got the current error with the next package, although it should be there. Unfortunatly I have limited rigths, because I 'm on the HPC

Comment: I've also had this problem running R scripts on the HPC at my institution. I got around it by manually specifying the `lib.loc` argument. Find the directory containing your R packages and set that as `lib.loc`. For example mine would look like `library(gridExtra, lib.loc = '~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5')`

Comment: Thank you qdread, that was the solution. I don't know why though. I tried before to explicitly state the library of all packages and got the error, but with the individual solution it works.